# Penser à une personne

Tags: pronoms-personnels

Salut !

D’après [cette vidéo](https://youtu.be/PdmqkbuGUII) (9:22) de Pierre et Noemi, on n’utilise pas ‘y’ avec le verbe penser quand on parle de penser à une personne.

Mais dans [cette video](https://youtu.be/_baLgHYQTsA) (5:07) de Netflix France, on voit ‘y’ utilisé avec penser pour parler d’une personne.

Est-ce que c’est fait exprès ou ils se sont trompés ?

Merci à l’avance.

Comment: Si tu écoutes attentivement (et les sous-titres sont corrects) **ils ne disent pas**  « qu'on  n’utilise pas ‘y’ avec le verbe penser quand on parle de penser à une personne ». Ils disent qu'en parlant d'une personne « on ne peut pas dire « il y pense souvent » parce que ça donnerait une sensation, ce serait péjoratif ».  Donc ils déconseillent de le dire parce que ce serait péjoratif.  Cette leçon est mauvaise. Ne pas employer y avec une personne est de l'hypercorrection, on l'emploie tous les jours dans le langage courant.

Comment: Dans le deuxième, il dit: Et ton ex, tu **y** pense? Techniquement, on devrait dire: Et ton ex, **tu penses à lui**? Mais, les gens disent y quand même.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On peut dire que la règle n'est pas appliquée de façon très stricte étant donnée qu'elle n'est pas facile à assimiler par la pratique ; selon la règle ils se sont trompés, et il n'existe pas de principe qui oblige à suivre cette tendance pour l'instant. Donc on peut continuer à appliquer la règle si on la connait.

- Et ton ex, tu penses à lui ?

La règle ne concerne pas que le verbe « penser » ; elle concerne tous les verbes dans le cas des personnes.

- Ton ami est gentil ; tu tiens à lui ?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Comment converted to a reply as it deserves it.</sub>

Si tu écoutes attentivement (et les sous-titres sont corrects), ils ne disent pas « qu'on n’utilise pas *y* avec le verbe penser quand on parle de penser à une personne ». Ils disent qu'en parlant d'une personne « on ne peut pas dire *il y pense souvent* parce que ça donnerait une sensation, ce serait péjoratif ».

Donc ils déconseillent de le dire parce que ce serait péjoratif.

Cette leçon est mauvaise. Ne pas employer **y** avec une personne est de l'hypercorrection, on l'emploie tous les jours dans le langage courant.